# How to Get Youtube Video URL Programmatically

Tags: android, youtube, playlist, android-youtube-api

In `Youtube` Playlist, I have many `Videos`, now I would like to share `Videos` with others (using Video URL - which is playing right now)

I am using below code to play `YouTube` Playlist in an `Android` application:

```
public static final String PlayList_ID = "PLP7qPet500dfglA7FFTxBmB_snxCaMHDJ";

 @Override
 public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
   boolean wasRestored) {

  youTubePlayer = player;

  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
    "YouTubePlayer.onInitializationSuccess()", 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  youTubePlayer.setPlayerStateChangeListener(myPlayerStateChangeListener);
  youTubePlayer.setPlaybackEventListener(myPlaybackEventListener);

  if (!wasRestored) {
   player.cuePlaylist(PlayList_ID);
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside onLoaded() you can get id from that id you can create url.

You can you this way.

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
        boolean wasRestored) {

    player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(new PlayerStateChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onVideoStarted() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoEnded() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoading() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaded(String mVideoId) {
            String url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + mVideoId
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(ErrorReason reason) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdStarted() {
        }
    });
}
```